# How to read from CDB (SQLite 3) database using PHP?

Tags: php, sqlite, cdb

I want to read the data from .CDB files which seems to be a SQLite 3 database files. I want to read data and handle it using PHP. Can you please suggest me a solution for that?

I tried ADOdb for PHP where the CDB format is not supporting in SQLite driver.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/pl/function.dba-open.php and http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=988

Comment: Thanks @Amir for your support. I am testing the code snippets from the link. Will get back here with results.

Comment: @Amir the dba wrapper was not working with the file which I am having (cdb). I got this cdb database file form CAMI software. This format is not supporting in PHP's DBA I guess. Is there any other way?